# Finding group sizes in matrices

Tags: algorithm, matrix, cluster-computing, detection

So i was wondering, is there an easy way to detect the sizes of adjacent same values in a matrix? For example, when looking at the matrix of values between 0 and 12 below:
The size of the group at [0,4] is 14 because there are 14 5's connected to each other. But the 1 and 4 are not connected.

[image]

Comment: so the values in the squares are irrelevant?

Comment: @Srini Well i only want to find the same values in the matrix, so if 8 and 5 would touch, they wouldn't count together, but only the 5's and 8's (should've picked a better example matrix)

Comment: ahh, i got it. It took me a while to notice that all values have a unique color :). thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a breath first search (well kind of, try to visualize the matrix as a tree)

Here's a pseudo python implementation. that does this. Would this work for you? Did you have a complexity in mind?

### Code

```
visited_nodes = set()

def find_adjacent_vals(target_val, cell_row, cell_column):
    if inside_matrix(cell_row, cell_column)
        cell = matrix(cell_row, cell_column)
        if cell not in visited_nodes:
            visited_nodes.add(cell)
            if cell.value == target_val:
                return (1 + 
                        find_adjacent_vals(target_val, cell_row + 1, cell_column) # below
                        +find_adjacent_vals(target_val, cell_row - 1, cell_column) # above
                        +find_adjacent_vals(target_val, cell_row, cell_column -1) # left
                        +find_adjacent_vals(target_val, cell_row, cell_column +1) # right
                        ))

print "Adjacent values count: " + str(find_adjacent_vals(target_val, target_row, target_column))
```

### Explanation

Let's say you start at a node, you start branching out visiting nodes you haven't visited before. You do this till you encounter no new cells of the same value. And each node is guaranteed to have only 1 parent node thanks to the set logic. Therefore no cell is double counted.

Comment: Ah yes this makes sense! Definitely will give this a try!